# Looking for an André Weil excerpt

Tags: reference-request, mathematicians

I just wasted the last hour on google looking in vain for an excerpt of Weil's writings describing the process of discovering mathematics.  I believe he once beautifully described the feeling of loss that accompanies the realization that the discovery you made seems, in retrospect, trivial.  Am I misremembering or just bad at googling?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting, I can relate to that sentiment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You might have the following passage in mind:

[image: De la métaphysique aux mathématiques]

It appears in A. Weil, *De la métaphysique aux mathématiques*, Science **60**, p. 52–56 (see also Collected Papers II, p. 406–412). The excerpt and the reference are taken from a preprint of A. Borel on A. Weil, [scan available here](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~aknapp/BorelOnWeil.pdf) (from [A. Knapp's homepage](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~aknapp/)).

**Edit:** As Bill pointed out in his answer below, this preprint is published:

1. In the [Proceedings of the American Philosophical Society](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1558329),
   Vol. **145**, No. 1 (Mar., 2001), pp. 107–114 (jstor-link, may be behind a paywall).
2. Reprinted and freely available as *[Mathematical Perspectives — André Weil](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-09-01264-6)* Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **46** (2009), 661–666.

**Added:** For further elaborations and context, I strongly recommend to read both, Borel's article I linked to and Weil's original, as well as [Weil's 1940 letter](http://www.ams.org/notices/200503/fea-weil.pdf) to his sister [Simone Weil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simone_Weil).

While I'm at it, I cannot refrain from *insisting* that you read *[The Apprenticeship of a Mathematician](http://books.google.com/books?id=73REHmJ9JNUC)*—preferably in its French original *[Souvenirs d'apprentissage](http://books.google.com/books?id=5UUZAQAAIAAJ)*—in case you haven't done so already.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the excerpt I had in mind. Thank you also for these links, and also to Bill.

Comment: I am aware I am arriving very late, but does anyone know a link to the original French version of the letter?

Comment: I have to note that it’s not _Science_ **60**, but _Sciences_ 1960, referring to [the French-language journal _Sciences_](http://www.sudoc.fr/038474913), ISSN 1141-1430, published by Hermann from 1959 to 1972.

Answer (score 12):

Having aleady OCRed Borel's article on Weil (see Theo's reply), I cannot resist posting a larger excerpt here, since it provides much further context that I suspect will help readers to better appreciate Weil's "search for elegance, beauty and hidden harmonies". Perhaps it will help motivate some readers to join in such fruitful endeavors. I too strongly endorse the literatured cited by Theo. It can prove highly inspirational to budding mathematical minds.
Edit: I just noticed that the AMS has a nicer [typeset version](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-04/S0273-0979-09-01264-6/S0273-0979-09-01264-6.pdf) of Borel's article from 2009 BAMS.

> His output offers an extraordinary combination of foundational work, to secure a solid 
>   basis in some area, of often decisive contributions at the cutting edge, solving old or new 
>   problems, and of forays into unknown territory, in the form of problems or conjectures, 
>   guided by a seemingly infallible sense for the directions into which one should forge ahead.
>
> Of course, I feel quite uncomfortable in making such a statement without backing it up 
>   in any way, so allow me to turn to the mathematicians to give an idea of these facets of his 
>   output in at least one area, algebraic geometry. The theorem he had proved in 1940 (see 
>   above) relied on some facts of algebraic geometry for some of which there was no solid 
>   reference. Moreover, the development of algebraic geometry, from "classical" (i.e. projective 
>   or affine complex varieties) to "abstract" (varieties over arbitrary fields), was also crying out 
>   for reliable foundations. It took him several years to supply them in a massive (and rather 
>   arid) treatise "Foundations of algebraic geometry" (1946), the only comprehensive basis for 
>   algebraic geometry for a number of years. Although dealing with a very general "abstract 
>   situation", he developed it in part in analogy with the theory of differentiable manifolds in 
>   differential geometry, and also with some constructions in algebraic topology. It was 
>   followed, among other items, by a monograph proving in full his 1940 result, by foundations 
>   for abelian varieties, fibre bundles in algebraic geometry, algebraic groups, the advocacy of 
>   the use of analytic fibre bundles in several complex variables, and in 1949, in a short Note, 
>   by a series of conjectures (soon called the Weil conjectures) which were to have an enormous 
>   impact on algebraic geometry. In particular, he postulated the existence of a cohomology 
>   theory in this set up, with properties allowing one to transcribe known arguments in algebraic 
>   topology, such as the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, a bold idea, unique to him, way ahead of 
>   its time. It was implemented some ten years later by A. Grothendieck (etale cohomology), 
>   and it took twenty-five years before Deligne proved the last, and by far hardest, of these 
>   conjectures, with far reaching consequences, not yet exhausted.
>
> So far, I have said little of what has arguably been Weil's most abiding interest in 
>   mathematics: "Zeta functions". The first one was used by B. Riemann in 1857 to study the 
>   distribution of prime numbers among positive integers. The "Riemann hypothesis" about the 
>   zeroes of this function is still unproved and generally viewed as the Holy Grail of 
>   mathematics. The introduction of this function to study the discrete (the integers) in a 
>   continuous framework (real or complex numbers) was quite revolutionary and proved to be 
>   immensely fruitful. Zeta functions, with corresponding Riemann hypotheses, have proliferated 
>   in analysis, algebraic geometry and number theory, and have always been on Weil's mind. 
>   (His 1940 theorem dealt with one kind and his 1949 conjectures with generalizations of it.) 
>   He was convinced that the problem of the Riemann hypothesis, even in the original case, had 
>   to be attacked broadly. How broadly can be only explained in mathematical terms of course, 
>   but he drew an analogy with the Rosetta Stone, which seems to me so typical of his thought 
>   processes and of the aesthetic component in his approach to mathematics that I cannot resist 
>   trying to give an idea of it, as imprecise as it has to be. It is developed in a short article: *De
>   la metaphysique aux mathematiques,* (From metaphysics to mathematics), Science 1960, 52-56; 
>   Collected Papers II, 406-412.
>
> "Metaphysics", he explains, is meant here in the sense of the 18'th century 
>   mathematicians, when they spoke of, say, "the metaphysics of the theory of equations":
>
> > "... a collection of vague analogies, difficult to grasp and difficult to formulate, 
> >         which nevertheless appeared to them to play an important role at certain 
> >         moments in the research and discovery in mathematics".
>
> and then he elaborates.
>
> > "Nothing is more fecund, all the mathematicians know it, than those obscure 
> >         analogies, the blurred reflections from one theory to another ... nothing gives 
> >         more pleasure to the researcher. One day the illusion drifts away, the 
> >         premonition changes to a certitude: the twin theories reveal their common 
> >         source before disappearing; as the Gita teaches it, knowledge and indifference 
> >         are reached at the same time. The metaphysics has become mathematics, ready 
> >         to form the subject matter of a treatise, the cold beauty of which cannot move 
> >         us anymore."
>
> Further:
>
> > "Fortunately for researchers, as the fogs clear away on some point, they 
> >         reappear on another. A major part of the Tokyo Colloquium [1955] was 
> >         devoted to the analogies between number theory and the theory of algebraic 
> >         functions. There we are still fully in metaphysics..."
>
> "Algebraic functions" alludes here to a theory built up by Riemann by analytical, 
>   transcendental means. To link it to number theory, guided by "obscure analogies", is a 
>   problem which had fascinated Weil early on (as already hinted by the title of his Thesis), and 
>   he felt that progress was still scant by 1960. Meanwhile, a third topic had appeared: 
>   "algebraic curves over finite fields" (the subject matter of his 1940 theorem), which was 
>   easier to relate to the other two and thus served as an intermediary. These items and many 
>   generalizations or related results formed an enormous amount of mathematics naturally 
>   divided into three parts, each with its own framework, (in brief, transcendental, arithmetic and 
>   algebraico-geometric) and techniques. As Weil puts it, we are faced with a text in three parts 
>   (he calls them columns), each written in its own language, called by him Riemannian, 
>   arithmetic and Italian respectively, in analogy with the Rosetta Stone. However, there is an 
>   huge difference: the latter contains the same text in the three languages (or rather, assuming 
>   this, Champollion was able to decipher Egyptian hieroglyphic writing), while we have here 
>   only in each column fragments of what is hoped to be similar texts, once completed.
>
> The task of the mathematicians, then, is to add translations of a given fragment into 
>   the other columns, to transform those obscure analogies into mathematics, and eventually 
>   build a dictionary which would allow one to pass from one column to the others. If it were 
>   sufficiently complete, then the Riemann hypothesis would be proved, Weil 
>   concludes, wondering how long mathematics will have to wait for a Champollion.
>
> As an illustration of his outlook, let me mention a paper ([1972], p. 249-64, in his 
>   Collected Papers III), where he formulates a statement in "Riemannian" language, the truth of 
>   which would imply that of the Riemann hypothesis (for many zeta functions), points out that 
>   it has an analogue in "Italian" which, in view of his earlier work, is a proven theorem, and 
>   comments that this provides for him, perhaps, the strongest evidence in favor of the original 
>   Riemann hypothesis, one of many examples of his unshakable belief in the unity and harmony 
>   of mathematics.
>
> Weil was indeed fluent in the three languages and many of his works can be 
>   interpreted as contributions to the dictionary, but not all, though. In particular, as befits a 
>   man with his cultural interests, he had a strong commitment to the history of mathematics, 
>   which culminated in a history of number theory from 1800 B.C. to 1800 A.D. (from 
>   Hammurapi to Legendre). Much earlier it had been at the origin of the Historical Notes in 
>   Bourbaki, to which he was a main contributor until he retired.
>
> As a mathematician, his work shows him to be at the same time an architect, a builder 
>   and a poet: an architect for fostering a global view of mathematics and striving to display its 
>   fundamental unity, a builder by his specific, often decisive, contributions to a great variety of 
>   topics and a poet by his search for elegance, beauty and hidden harmonies.
>
> ARMAND BOREL
>   Professor Emeritus
>   School of Mathematics
>   Institute for Advanced Study
>   Princeton, NJ 08540

Comment: Oh great! Thanks for that!

Comment: @Theo Perhaps you should link also to said BAMS article so that those with access (everybody?) can enjoy the higher quality.

Comment: I just did. I also added a link to the original printed version in the Proceedings of the American Philosophical Society.